# Why is 'Nothing' as output in ' do{ let{ the= Just "Hi!"}; _ <- sequence [the,Nothing]; pure "no way!" }'

Tags: haskell, monads

Just like title, codes like below:

`do{ let{ the= Just "Hi!"}; _ <- sequence [the,Nothing]; pure "no way!" }`

The Output is `Nothing`.
My question is how can I be sure, this Do-block is a Maybe-Monad?
And what is exactly function of `do` as Syntactic sugar?

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're asking - but it produces `Nothing` because `sequence [the,Nothing]` is `Nothing`, and the way the `Maybe` monad works is that any `Nothing` value encountered along the way automatically makes the whole computation return `Nothing`.

Comment: You can see that this works in the maybe monad since `[the,Nothing] :: [Maybe String]` and `sequence` turns `[m a]` into `m [a]`, so in this case produces `_ :: Maybe [String]`. Anyway you can ask GHCi about its type.

Comment: Please do not put code anywhere except main body, where you can format it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is how can I be sure, this `do`-block is a `Maybe`-Monad?

You can perform type inference, just like the Haskell compiler does. In order to do that we first should *desugar* the do-notation, as described in the [*Haskell '10 report*](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14).

Your expression is equivalent to:

```
let the = Just "Hi!" in sequence [the,Nothing] >> pure "no way!"
```

So now that we know that, let us look at the types. It is clear that `the` is a `the :: Maybe String`, so that means that the list of `[the, Nothing]` has type `[the, Nothing] :: [Maybe String]`.

The type of `sequence` is [**`sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence), so that means that `t` is `t ~ []` here, and that `m ~ Maybe` and `a ~ String`. With these type equivalences `suquence` in this example has type `sequence :: [Maybe String] -> Maybe [String]`. This thus means that `sequence [the, Nothing]` has type `sequence [the, Nothing] :: Maybe [String]`.

The `(>>)` function has type [**`Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62-). Since the left operand of `>>` has type `Maybe [String]` this thus means that `m ~ Maybe` and `a ~ String`. The right operand is `pure` "no way!". `pure` has type [**`pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:pure). We can derive that `a ~ String` here, and since the right operand needs to have type `m b` from the `(>>)` function type, this thus means that `m b ~ f a`, and hence that `f ~ Maybe`.

We thus can derive that the type of `(>>) (sequence [the, Nothing]) (pure "No way!")` is `Maybe String`.

> what is exactly function of do as Syntactic sugar?

Syntactical sugar is used to make notation more convenient. For the above example, it probably does not matter that much. For some larger expressions, `do` will filter out some noise, because it hides the `>>=` operators in between statements, and furthermore the `f >>= \x -> ...` is written as `x <- f; ...` which makes it sometimes easier to track what variable is bounded to what expressions.